# high-water mark of number of sessions or connections

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning

I was wondering if we can query/obtain the high-water mark of number of sessions or connections reached in a Postgres database. Is there a view or command that can provide this information.  The pg_stat_database shows the current number of connections, but not the high-water mark a database had reached.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no builtin feature to provide you with such data.  However, depending on how and what you monitor, it might be easy to have it somewhere.

Comment: You could sample the information from `pg_stat_activity` into some table.